# How to keep all elements at sticky position until a trigger is called?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-position, sticky

I have a page where an image is decreased in size while scrolling. Once it reaches a specific size another image appears. From there on the scroll behavior should be the same as in scrollytelling approaches.

My problem right now is that all the subsequent `div`'s are not "waiting" for this event of image change. I can only tell the first subsequent `div` to stop until this event occurs and change its `position` to `relative` once it occurs. But with this solution, it seems to be more messed up.

[Here is a JSFiddle with a sample setup.](https://jsfiddle.net/ycohmaj1/4/) I would like that none of the text div's move until the red div appears. And then it should start moving from its current position.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue myself (in some way).

I added a container div to all content after the div with the images and made its `opacity: hidden`. While scrolling, the content is actually scrolling upwards, but it cannot be seen. Once the images change I add a `margin-top` to the content container with the value of the scrolled distance (+ some buffer) and remove the `opacity: hidden` class.

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy3fx7od/2/)

However, this is not the solution described in the question, where the content should be visible and "wait" at its position, but for my circumstances, it is an acceptable answer. But I will not make this the accepted answer of my question.